# MVC where model has no intrinsic visual representation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, visualization, strategy-pattern

I'm developing an application in Java with MVC architecture. Doing so has greatly decoupled and simplified my code, but the problem is that the model has no intrinsic visual representation. That is, there are no characters, no specific enemies, no buttons, no text boxes - the model is made up of hundreds of instances of one type of object. Each instance is controlled by an instance of a strategy pattern (technically, it's a hierarchy of strategy patterns); it is the only differing point between each instance in the application. The type of strategy each instance uses should therefore ideally make it look slightly different than others around it.

I'd like to avoid a giant if statement chain with dozens of "instance of" calls checking for the type of strategy used when developing a view for this application. I'd also like to avoid a similar chain using an enumeration. Any suggestions as to how I can make my view without succumbing to a massive if chain? Any suggestions as to how I could design my view properly so that it wouldn't be so tightly coupled to the strategy instances?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Please replace some of your prose with code examples.

Comment: Are you interested in presenting to the user the strategy selected, or the results of that strategy?

Comment: @DJClayworth: The strategies controlling the main objects in the model are hierarchies of simpler strategies. What I would like to display are the capabilities of each sub-strategy. For instance, if one model object moves and attacks, I want a clear marker for those two strategies. The marker could be anything; it could be a colour or a shield on roller blades. The point is that the user needs some clue as to what it can do.

@Kirk Woll: Code wouldn't help here. I would have to give you an enormous portion of my source to show you what's going on. IMHO it's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DJClayworth asks the critical question:

> Are you interested in presenting to the user the strategy [to be] selected, or the results of that strategy?

Assuming you'll need both, let the model contain an enumeration relating strategy names, implementations and descriptive text. The implementation can use a [*class literal as a runtime-type token*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).

In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite), `enum Rule` serves all three purposes as an implicit model. It supplies a legible name and description, as well as a constant representing a particular composite strategy. No `case` statements are required.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. Are you suggesting that I create an enumerator to identify the different strategy objects where each value of the enumerator is tied to a visualization (just as enum Rule is tied to a constant and a property in your example)? If so, would this not tightly couple the view and the model? Or would providing a "properties" file of some sort sufficiently decouple the two?

Comment: There should be no new coupling. When the controller sees that a new strategy has been requested, the chosen strategy should be updated in the model; the model then notifies the view of hte change. When the view learns of the model's new strategy, it can act accordingly. Your strategies should already implement the interfaces required to effect the new view. The example's `enum`, relating name and class, is an implementation detail that happens to enforce the singleton property.

Comment: "When the view learns of the model's new strategy, it can act accordingly" -- Would this not require an if chain? I.e., wouldn't "acting accordingly" still require the view to run through a list of possible strategies to see which visualization is most appropriate?

Comment: Not if the strategies implement a common interface.

Comment: They do, but I fail to see how this can help produce a visualization without the model explicitly telling the view how to represent it. I feel you have gone from strategy to visualization via an interface without adequate explanation; I cannot see how you made the jump. I am very willing to read and learn from your responses but I seem to be missing some key information that would allow me to see how your solution would work.

Comment: Let each concrete strategy either implement an interface having a `getMarker()` method, or add such a method to the strategy itself. The method would define the means of obtaining a related symbol—a name, a path or even an `Icon` itself. Later, when the view needs to render a given strategy in context, it simply invokes `getMarker()`. There's no decision to make; the view just renders whatever visual representation the model tells it.

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. This goes back to the "no intrinsic visualization" problem; the model has no natural way of being drawn or displayed. That being said, this probably is the easiest way to do things and exactly what to be drawn can be specified in a properties file somewhere if the visualization ever needs to be changed. I'll go with that. Thank you!